# MD5 to Blowfish encryption?

Tags: md5, encryption, blowfish

Can anyone give me an idea bout this.. I was assigned to decrypt passwords from our LDAP DB and then encrypt them using blowfish algo since we are going to use openfire system. Transfer of data from one DB to another is not that much of a problem, just these "passwords".. Is there any way to convert MD5 encryption to blowfish? am i going to decrypt it first? im using Perl here. PLS HELP?

Answer (score 10):

MD5 is not a symmetric encryption algorithm, it is a one-way hash. There is no way to "decrypt" passwords stored using the MD5 algorithm.

(Unless you have a very large amount of computing power available, or a very long time.)

Answer (score 4):

Set up a web site somewhere and tell everyone to log in to it with their current password.

When they log in, you can capture their password in cleartext and then encrypt it with blowfish.

This would be even simpler if you can hook in to a site that they already log in to frequently enough (like web mail or something).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Greg, you can't really decrypt them. One option however would be to encrypt the hashed passwords using blowfish

Comment: And what would that accomplish?

Comment: increased security and backwards compatibility mostly

Comment: Is what you're trying to say run the hash algorithm as blowfish on the MD5's --> blowfish(md5(password)) in the new database?

Comment: yeah, it does have it's problems, but I merely mention it as an option